# gridview image problem

Tags: asp.net

work on C# vs05 asp.net .want to show image on gridview....From Northwind database .Table..Categories .this table contain the picture column......i want to show this column on my gridview.......

my code is bellow.............

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="284px" PageSize="3">
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Btw, no need to use so many ellipsis : P.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Can you add the code for your SqlDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ImageField`, like so:

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField='<%# "ThumbNailImage.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Picture") %>'></asp:ImageField>
```